# Where is ->getForm() method located for Symfony3 CreateFormFactory

Tags: php, symfony

First off, I am building using Symfony components. I am using 3.4. I was following the form tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/form.html which lead me to this page
https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#usage

I noticed that Symfony added a Form directory to my application.

[image: form directory added and basic classes added]

This was great! I thought I was on my way. So, in my controller, I added this line.

```
   $form = Forms::createFormFactory();
```

When I tried loading the page, everything went well with no error messages until I added the next two lines.

```
 ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension())
 ->getForm();
```

I removed the ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension()) line and left the ->getForm() thinking it would process without the add method call. It did not. So, I backed up to see if the IDE would type hint for me.
In the IDE PHPStorm, these are the methods that I have access to but not getForm per the tutorial

[image: trying to find the method getForm()]

Every tutorial I have tried ends with not being able to find some method that does not exist. What do I need to install in order to have access to the ->getForm() method?

**UPDATE:**
I have made a couple of steps forward.

```
    $form = Forms::createFormFactory()
        ->createBuilder(TaskType::class);
```

The code above loads with no errors. (Why is still fuzzy). But next stop is the createView(). None existant also. I only get hinted with create().
Reading between the lines in this video help with the last two steps. https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-forms/render-form-bootstrap#play

**UPDATE 2:**

[image: Renderer not]

This is what I have now.

```
    $session = new Session();
    $csrfManager = new CsrfTokenManager();
    $help = new \Twig_ExtensionInterface();
    $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
           ->getFormFactory();
    $form = $formFactory->createBuilder(TaskType::class)
        ->getForm();

    //$form->handleRequest();

    $loader = new FilesystemLoader('../../templates/billing');
    $twig = new Environment($loader, [
        'debug' => true,
    ]);
    $twig->addExtension(new HeaderExtension());
    $twig->addExtension(new DebugExtension());
    $twig->addExtension($help, FormRendererEngineInterface::class);

    return $twig->render('requeueCharge.html.twig', [
        'payments' => 'Charge',
        'reportForm' => $form->createView()

    ]);
```

Does anyone know of an update standalone for example? The one that everyone keeps pointing two is 6 years old. There have been many things deprecated in that time period. So, it is not an example to follow.

Comment: You started by saying you were using components but then provided a link to the framework documentation.  You need to be clear about the difference.  Are you using the Symfony framework or just the Form component?  If just the Form component then follow: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html (notice the word 'component' in the url).

Comment: Yes, I have been to this page. I placed the framework link because I was trying to figure out why the ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension()) that is in the example on the page is giving me Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::addExtension(). I am entering the code in my project one line at a time to see where it fails.

Comment: I can see the IDE is type hinting from the FormFactoryInterface.php class. So, I should be using createBuilder() and not getForm(). Trying to follow the bread crumbs that are given in the program.

Comment: Ok, I finally get it in my head that createBuilder because I am not extending AbstractController. https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-forms-in-controllers. But I still unclear on where these items live and are called from.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form class and method `createFormFactory` must return object that implement [FormBuilderInterface](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/FormBuilderInterface.php) then `getForm` method will be available. You need create `formBuilder` object. 
But this can't be called from static method because `formBuilder` object need dependency from DI container. Look at [controller](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/FormBuilder.php).

If you want you need register your own class in DI and create formBuilder object with dependencies and return that instance of object.

**EDIT**
You don't need to use abstract controller. You can create your own class which is registered in DI for geting dependencies. In that class you create method which create new FormBuilder(..dependencies from DI from your class ...) and return instance of that FormBuilder. Then you can inject your class in controller via DI.

Example (not tested)

```
// class registered in DI
class CustomFormFactory
{
  private $_factory;
  private $_dispatcher;

  public CustomFormFactory(EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher, FormFactoryInterface $factory)
  {
    $_dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    $_factory = $factory;
  }


  public function createForm(?string $name, ?string $dataClass, array $options = []): FormBuilderInterface
  {
    // create instance in combination with DI dependencies (factory..) and your parameters 
    return new FormBuilder($name, $dataClass, $_dispatcher, $_factory, $options);
  }
}
```

Usage

```
$factory = $this->container->get('CustomFormFactory');
$fb = $factory->createForm();
$form = $fb->getForm();
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes after looking into the DI, it brought me back to this tutorial. I will give it another read.

Comment: I don't have the AbstractController to be able to extend it in the TaskController. What am I suppose to do to access the AbstractController?