# Symfony 3.4 Uncaught Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException: No block "form_start" found while rendering the standalone form

Tags: php, symfony, twig

This is a continuation of a previous question. 
[Where is ->getForm() method located for Symfony3 CreateFormFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966689/where-is-getform-method-located-for-symfony3-createformfactory)

I got past that hurdle and now the system is unable to locate the template directory. I am still following the Symfony guide. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/form.html#rendering-the-form

Referring to line 23 of the guide looks like the real directory needs to be passed to twig. See the image below for reference.

[image: Symfony Twig Bridge Directory location]

I know it looks redundant but It was an attempt to just tell Twig where the template is located. This returned an error.

```
  Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: The "C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\future5_2\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge../../templates/billing" directory does not exist ("C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\future5_2\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge../../templates/billing"). in C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\future5_2\vendor\twig\twig\src\Loader\FilesystemLoader.php:106
```

As you can see on the left where the template directory is located. It seems as though Twig wants to look in its own folder instead of the folder location is given.  I have tried a couple of different variations.

```
    $loader = new FilesystemLoader(['../../templates/billing',
        $vendorTwigBridgeDirectory.'requeueCharge.html.twig']);
```

This produces an error also.

```
  Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: The "C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\future5_2\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge\requeueCharge.html.twig" directory does not exist
```

Which the error message is true, the location does not exist. But then I am still left with how to redirect twig to the folder where the view is located?

**UPDATE**

I just went ahead and created the folder and moved the layout.html.twig file to the location. Now the error message is

```
 Uncaught Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException: No block "form_start" found while rendering the form. 
 Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Arr in C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\future5_2\templates\billing\requeueCharge.html.twig on line 8
```

Line 8 in that file reads as follows:

```
    {% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
    {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    {% block body %}

        <div class="container">
        <h3></h3>

        {{ form_start(reportForm) }}
            {{ form_widget(reportForm) }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        {{ form_end(reportForm) }}
```

The problem was not in the template/billing but code needed to point to the built-in templates that come with the component twig-bridge. In the example, the folder Resource/views/Forms is a real directory that has to be used.

Comment: `C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\future5_2\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge../../templates/billing` <-- you are clearly missing an extra slash in there

Comment: I placed the slash at the end and the same issue is occurring. Thanks for pointing that out. : - )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out is that I need to read more closely and investigate every line of code that is presented. So, that is a self-evaluation. This is what solved the riddle.

I ended up with this:

```
    use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfExtension;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\PhpBridgeSessionStorage;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\UriSafeTokenGenerator;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage;
    use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader;
    use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
    use Twig\Environment;
    use Twig\Extension\DebugExtension;
    use Twig\HeaderExtension;
    use Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
    use Twig\RuntimeLoader\FactoryRuntimeLoader;

class RequeueChargesController extends Controller
{
public function requeueCharge()
{
    $defaultFormTheme = 'form_div_layout.html.twig';
    $vendorDirectory = dirname(__DIR__, 2).'\vendor';

    $translator = new Translator('en');
    $translator->addLoader('xlf', new XliffFileLoader());

    //$form->handleRequest();
    $session = new Session(new PhpBridgeSessionStorage());
    $csrfGenerator = new UriSafeTokenGenerator();
    $csrfStorage = new SessionTokenStorage($session);
    $csrfManager = new CsrfTokenManager($csrfGenerator, $csrfStorage);

    $appVariableReflection = new \ReflectionClass('\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable');
    $vendorTwigBridgeDirectory = dirname($appVariableReflection->getFileName());

    $loader = new FilesystemLoader(['../../templates/billing/',
        $vendorTwigBridgeDirectory.'/Resources/views/Form']);

    $twig = new Environment($loader, [
        'debug' => true,
    ]);
    $twig->addExtension(new HeaderExtension());
    $twig->addExtension(new DebugExtension());
    $twig->addExtension(new TranslationExtension($translator));

    $formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine([$defaultFormTheme], $twig);
    $twig->addRuntimeLoader(new FactoryRuntimeLoader([
        FormRenderer::class => function () use ($formEngine, $csrfManager) {
        return new FormRenderer($formEngine, $csrfManager);
        }
    ]));

    $twig->addExtension(new FormExtension());

    $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
        ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension())
        ->addExtension(new CsrfExtension($csrfManager))
        ->getFormFactory();

    $form = $formFactory->createBuilder(TaskType::class)
        ->getForm();

    return $twig->render('requeueCharge.html.twig', [
        'payments' => 'Charge',
        'reportForm' => $form->createView()

    ]);
}
}
```

The example code that was given in https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/form.html#rendering-the-form needed little alteration to work.

You can compare the example with what I had to do to get it working in the OpenEMR codebase. If you have any questions, try me.